# Start a Service use an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I want to start a Service use an Activity. To be specific, it is IntentService. But I have two problems:

When starting my code

```
private void switchService(boolean isEnable, String serviceName){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName(TestPhoneServiceActivity.this, serviceName);
        if(isEnable){
            startService(intent);
        }
        else{
            if(isServiceRunning(serviceName)){
                stopService(intent);
                while(isServiceRunning(serviceName)){

                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
        }
    }
```

DDMS has the error:`Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.xx.android/.AndroidPhoneService }: not found`

But the path is right. So what is the problem？And also I want to call a system service. Should I write it into configuration file?

Then I start IntentService use intent.setClass.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
```

I can not find this service object. Is the IntentService finished and destroyed automatically？And the life cycle of IntentService is different from the other Service?

Comment: Have you added your service in manifest file?

Comment: don't stop an intentservice, it stops itself when it's done

Comment: post the manifest part where you describe the service

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in the class of the service instead of the name of the class of the service like so

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName(TestPhoneServiceActivity.this, MyIntentService.class);
    if(isEnable){
        startService(intent);
    }
```

The intent service stops itself after work has completed if you start multiple of the same intent service it will be queued behind and executed sequentially, so the else block is kind of redundant in your case.

And make sure you have declared the service inside your manifest.